# Being capable of doing multiple things within if-else statements in Python?

Tags: python

Okay, so I am working on creating a cash register command-line program in Python. I want the program to be capable of telling how many twenties, tens, fives, ones, quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies should be given as change. I know what equations need to be down, and I can figure out how to print out the twenties, but I can't seem to figure out where to go from there. For example, my code looks something like:

```
    if change >= 2000:
      twenties = change / 2000
      moneyform = "%i" % twenties
      print("Twenties "), moneyform
    else:
      print("Twenties: 0")
    next = change - 2000
    if next >= 1000:
      tens = next / 1000
      moneyformtwo = "%i" % tens
      print("Tens "), moneyformtwo
    else:
      print("Tens: 0")
```

And so on, and so forth.

Now I know I'm not doing this correctly, but what happens is the twenties are printed correctly, but then the program stops without continuing on to the tens. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: That code won't run because your indentation doesn't make any sense. Please reproduce the indentation you actually have so we can tell you why it's wrong.

Comment: @khelwood Okay. Done.

Comment: Looks like you have an if-else-elif-else block here, which is not legal python. an elif can't come after an else. Please post your actual code.

Comment: You probably just want to replace that `elif` with an `if`.

Comment: I see one logic problem: suppose `change` is 25. you print "Twenties: 0", and then subtract 2000 from `change`. `next` is now -1975.

Answer (score 2):

Why even use if /else statements?

```
twenties = int(change / 2000)
change = change % 2000

tens = int(change / 1000)
change = change % 1000

fives = int(change / 500)
change = change % 500
```

print the results at the end

Edit: I made the same assumption in my answer that whole numbers represented cents, as you did in your question statement. Try this at the top:

```
amount_paid = 50.00
price = 24.50
change = amount_paid*100 - price*100
```

Comment: If I do this, and I enter 24.50 as the price, and 50.00 as the amount given, it says I should give 0 twenties back?

Comment: @HunterWatkins - In the text of your question, you seem to make the assumption that whole numbers represent cents. tom reasonably made the same assumption in his answer as you made in your question. So if you enter 24.50 as the price and 50.00 as the amount given, that's interpreted as 24.5 cents and 50 cents. Your change is 25.5 cents. Fair enough.

Comment: By the way - The reason I use "int()" is that in some versions of python, I believe you will get a floating point for "change/2000".  This code should work in all versions.